# handle socket.request.session.passport undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io, passport.js

I'm writing a node express application which offers some interaction between users by mean of socketio.
There is a login page, and I'm using passport to handle the session.
I'm importing the passport session into socket.io using:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(https)
io.use((socket,next) => sessionMware(socket.request, socket.request.res, bext)
```

where `sessionMware` is defined as:

```js
var sessionMware = session({
  genid:(req) => {
    return Date.now() + "_" + uuid()
  },
  store: new FileStore(),
  secret: 'not_whatever',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  name: 'mis_id',
})
```

then inside the `onConnection` function, which is called as the application gets a socket connection (`io.sockets.on('connection', onConnection)`), I access `socket.request.session.passport.user` to get the username of the connected client.
The solution works, but since I'm still debugging the application I'm often restarting the server in a local environment, and every now and then `socket.request.session.passport.user` returns `undefined` and consequently the application crashes.
I can't really figure out how to reproduce the bug exactly, but in the mean time I was wondering:

**QUESTION**
Is there any way to handle this bug in such a way that:

```js
function onConnection(socket){
   if(socket.request.session.passport.user == 'undefined'){
      // ROUTE THE CLIENT TO LOGIN PAGE...?
   }
}
```

Please let me know if you need specific details about the structure of my code...I was just trying to highlight the issue. I'll be happy to edit my post.
Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue though do not think I need the redirect.  To help define/reproduce the issue, socket.request.user is defined upon the user login, and stays even if the client is refreshing their browser and reconnecting. It is when the server gets restarted (via hot reload or otherwise) that the user session information is lost in the socket and the user is then undefined.